# Self-Generated barcodes on PDF filled with iTextSharp vb.net

Tags: javascript, vb.net, pdf

I'm developing an application that generates and prints a PDF form using iTextSharp and vb.net.

The PDF template is a four pages combined document. The first page is a report about an single patient and contains  five mandatory fields (marked in red). This information will be used to self-generate a PDF417 barcode on the bottom of the page, to ID the patient.
The three other pages are individual laboratory submission forms for different exams for this specific patient. These slips also have some of the information from those mandatory fields on the first page. These fields get filled automatically ( I sense a javascript here) .Each slip also self-generates a related barcode.

The remaining fields of the first page only must be thoroughly filled  after receiving and disclosing the lab results to the patient.

On this first page There are a few dropdownlists that depend on each other. They are not cascading but  they contain answers for question that may or may not require additional questions to be answered about the same subject. I mean, sometimes i can skip a question  based on a previous answer about that same subject. In some other instances, both questions must be answered.

I successfully automated form creation and fill-out with my code, but i'm struggling specifically with these dropdownlists that depend on each other.
By passing the index as parameter, I don't get the box to display the answer itself, but the numeric index. Something tells me that there may be some boolean variable behind, some javascript that I've been bypassing, when I fill the forms out using iTextSharp, instead of clicking and selecting.

As a result, I get an invalid barcode being self-generated.
I've tried passing the answer itself (a string) instead of the index.
It did fill the form correctly but I ended up with an abnormal wider barcode.
I believe the script behind the barcode uses the index, not the text within the field. At this point I can't make any progress on my own.

My guess here is trying to find out exactly what the embedded code is and hopefully  trigger via code whatever event needs to be triggered in order for this barcode to work correctly.`enter code here`
Any Help would be very much appreciated.
Here's the PDF in question, as well as my code.
Forgive me if it doesn't look pretty. I'm new to vb.net 
Thanks in advance.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByxujotstiajcTJPNkt4TW51V3M

Function GenerateForms() As Boolean

```
    Dim pdfTemplate As String = DefaultPath + " \CTRForm.pdf"
    Dim pdfReader As New PdfReader(pdfTemplate)
    Dim pdfStamper As PdfStamper
    Dim AuxOption As String
    Dim OrderingInfo(2) As String

    'ThisCTR = DefaultPath + "\CTR " + Form2.MetroDOC.Text
    ThisCTR = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop + "\CTR " + Form2.MetroDOC.Text
    '********************** Check if a Folder for this CTR Session Exists
    If Directory.Exists(ThisCTR) = False Then
        Directory.CreateDirectory(ThisCTR)
    End If
    '*************************
    newFile = ThisCTR
    If Form2.MetroSiteID.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
        newFile = newFile + "\01362_"
    Else
        newFile = newFile + "\01364_"
    End If
    newFile = newFile + FlipDate(Form2.MetroDOC.Text) + "_" + FlipDate(Form2.MetroDOB.Text)

    Select Case Form2.MetroGender.SelectedIndex
        Case 0
            newFile = newFile + "_1_"
        Case 1
            newFile = newFile + "_2_"
        Case 2
            newFile = newFile + "_3_"
        Case 3
            newFile = newFile + "_4_"
        Case 4
            newFile = newFile + "_5_"
        Case 5
            newFile = newFile + "_6_"
    End Select
    newFile = newFile + Form2.MetroLblClientCode.Text + ".pdf"
    Try

        pdfStamper = New PdfStamper(pdfReader, New FileStream(newFile, FileMode.Create), "\DC", True) '\6c
        ' pdfStamper.Writer.SetPdfVersion(PdfWriter.PDF_VERSION_1_7)
        Dim pdfFormFields As AcroFields = pdfStamper.AcroFields

        ' Fill out PDF form fields
        'jump to the end of the routine just for implementing purposes
        ' GoTo SkippingSomeCommands
        Select Case Form2.MetroOrderingInfo.SelectedIndex
            Case 0
                OrderingInfo(0) = "SANTO"
                OrderingInfo(1) = "ALVARO"
                OrderingInfo(2) = "6176426213"

            Case 1
                OrderingInfo(0) = "PINTO"
                OrderingInfo(1) = "ANDERSON"
                OrderingInfo(2) = "61777870557"

            Case 2
                OrderingInfo(0) = "AMORIM"
                OrderingInfo(1) = "CRISTIANO"
                OrderingInfo(2) = "8579286831"

            Case 3
                OrderingInfo(0) = "RONCANCIO"
                OrderingInfo(1) = "GABRIEL"
                OrderingInfo(2) = "6178255897"

            Case 4
                OrderingInfo(0) = "KRIEGER"
                OrderingInfo(1) = "MAGNA"
                OrderingInfo(2) = "9789701250"

            Case 5
                OrderingInfo(0) = "DUARTE"
                OrderingInfo(1) = "MURILLO"
                OrderingInfo(2) = "6177642091"

        End Select
        AuxOption = ""
        Select Case Form2.MetroInsurance.SelectedIndex
            Case 0
                AuxOption = "1" 'Aetna
                pdfFormFields.SetField("CTR_V41[0].Page1[0].insure_status[0]", "6")'Private Insurance
            Case 1
                AuxOption = "2" 'BCBSMA
                pdfFormFields.SetField("CTR_V41[0].Page1[0].insure_status[0]", "6")'Private Insurance
            Case 2
                AuxOption = "3" 'BMC Healthnet
                pdfFormFields.SetField("CTR_V41[0].Page1[0].insure_status[0]", "6")'Private Insurance
            Case 3
                AuxOption = "4" 'Celticare
                pdfFormFields.SetField("CTR_V41[0].Page1[0].insure_status[0]", "6")'Private Insurance
            Case 4
                AuxOption = "5" 'CIGNA
                pdfFormFields.SetField("CTR_V41[0].Page1[0].insure_status[0]", "6")'Private Insurance
            Case 5
                AuxOption = "6" 'Fallon
                pdfFormFields.SetField("CTR_V41[0].Page1[0].insure_status[0]", "6")'Private Insurance
            Case 6
                AuxOption = "7" 'Harvard Pilgrim
                pdfFormFields.SetField("CTR_V41[0].Page1[0].insure_status[0]", "6")'Private Insurance
            Case 7
                AuxOption = "8" 'Health New England
                pdfFormFields.SetField("CTR_V41[0].Page1[0].insure_status[0]", "6")'Private Insurance
            Case 8
                AuxOption = "9" 'MassHealth
                pdfFormFields.SetField("CTR_V41[0].Page1[0].insure_status[0]", "1") 'MassHealth/Medicaid
            Case 9
                AuxOption = "10" 'Medicare
                pdfFormFields.SetField("CTR_V41[0].Page1[0].insure_status[0]", "2")'Medicare

            Case 10
                AuxOption = "11" 'Neighborhood Health Plan
                pdfFormFields.SetField("CTR_V41[0].Page1[0].insure_status[0]", "6")'Private Insurance
            Case 11
                AuxOption = "12" 'Network Health
                pdfFormFields.SetField("CTR_V41[0].Page1[0].insure_status[0]", "6")'Private Insurance
            Case 12
                AuxOption = "13" 'Tufts
                pdfFormFields.SetField("CTR_V41[0].Page1[0].insure_status[0]", "6")'Private Insurance
            Case 13
                AuxOption = "14" 'Unicare
                pdfFormFields.SetField("CTR_V41[0].Page1[0].insure_status[0]", "6")'Private Insurance
            Case 14
                AuxOption = "15" 'None
                pdfFormFields.SetField("CTR_V41[0].Page1[0].insure_status[0]", "4") '4 = No Insurance
                pdfFormFields.SetField("CTR_V41[0].Page1[0].no_insure[0]", "2") '2 = If No Insurance Did Receive assist.? = No
        End Select
        'Page 1
        pdfFormFields.SetField("CTR_V41[0].Page1[0].sub_req[0]", "8") '8 selects HIV/HCV + CTGC + Syphilis

        If Form2.MetroSiteID.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
            pdfFormFields.SetField("CTR_V41[0].Page1[0].site[0]", "01362")
        Else
            pdfFormFields.SetField("CTR_V41[0].Page1[0].site[0]", "01364")
        End If

        pdfFormFields.SetField("CTR_V41[0].Page1[0].dt_sesn[0]", FilterNumbers(Form2.MetroDOC.Text))
        pdfFormFields.SetField("CTR_V41[0].Page1[0].clientcode[0]", Form2.MetroLblClientCode.Text)
        pdfFormFields.SetField("CTR_V41[0].Page1[0].dob[0]", FilterNumbers(Form2.MetroDOB.Text))
        Select Case Form2.MetroGender.SelectedIndex
            Case 0
                pdfFormFields.SetField("CTR_V41[0].Page1[0].currentgender[0]", "1") '1= male
                pdfFormFields.SetField("CTR_V41[0].Page1[0].birthsex[0]", "1")'1 = male
            Case 1
                pdfFormFields.SetField("CTR_V41[0].Page1[0].currentgender[0]", "2") '2= female
                pdfFormFields.SetField("CTR_V41[0].Page1[0].birthsex[0]", "2")'1 = female
            Case 2
                pdfFormFields.SetField("CTR_V41[0].Page1[0].currentgender[0]", "3") '3 = trans m-f
                pdfFormFields.SetField("CTR_V41[0].Page1[0].birthsex[0]", "1")'1 = male
            Case 3
                pdfFormFields.SetField("CTR_V41[0].Page1[0].currentgender[0]", "4") '4 = trans f-m
                pdfFormFields.SetField("CTR_V41[0].Page1[0].birthsex[0]", "2")'1 = female
            Case 4
                pdfFormFields.SetField("CTR_V41[0].Page1[0].currentgender[0]", "5") '5 = trans Unspec.
                pdfFormFields.SetField("CTR_V41[0].Page1[0].birthsex[0]", "3")'3 =  declined
            Case 5
                pdfFormFields.SetField("CTR_V41[0].Page1[0].currentgender[0]", "6") '6 = declined
                pdfFormFields.SetField("CTR_V41[0].Page1[0].birthsex[0]", "3")'3 =  declined
            Case 5
        End Select

        pdfFormFields.SetField("CTR_V41[0].Page1[0].state[0]", "MA")
        pdfFormFields.SetField("CTR_V41[0].Page1[0].zip[0]", Form2.MetroZipCode.Text)
        'pdfFormFields.SetField("CTR_V41[0].Page1[0].housing_status[0]", "Stably housed") 'housing status stably by default
        'pdfFormFields.SetField("CTR_V41[0].Page1[0].election1[0]", "Tested confidentially") 'answers Tested Confidentially
        'pdfFormFields.SetField("CTR_V41[0].Page1[0].dt_sample1[0]", FilterNumbers(Form2.MetroDOC.Text))
        'pdfFormFields.SetField("CTR_V41[0].Page1[0].tech1[0]", "Serum") 'answers Serum by default
        'pdfFormFields.SetField("CTR_V41[0].Page1[0].confirm1", "Yes") 'answers Serum specimen provided as yes by default
        'pdfFormFields.SetField("CTR_V41[0].Page1[0].hav_vax[0]", "No") 'answers no as default but can be manually changed to previously vaccinated
        'pdfFormFields.SetField("CTR_V41[0].Page1[0].hbv_vax[0]", "No")

        'Page 2, 

        pdfFormFields.SetField("CTR_V41[0].Page2[0].namelast_p[0]", UCase(Form2.MetroLastName.Text))
        pdfFormFields.SetField("CTR_V41[0].Page2[0].namefrst_p[0]", UCase(Form2.MetroFirstName.Text))
        pdfFormFields.SetField("CTR_V41[0].Page2[0].street_p[0]", UCase(Form2.MetroStAddress.Text))
        pdfFormFields.SetField("CTR_V41[0].Page2[0].city_p[0]", UCase(Form2.MetroCity.Text))
        pdfFormFields.SetField("CTR_V41[0].Page2[0].phonenum_p[0]", FilterNumbers(Form2.MetroPhone.Text))
        pdfFormFields.SetField("CTR_V41[0].Page2[0].namelast_v[0]", OrderingInfo(0))
        pdfFormFields.SetField("CTR_V41[0].Page2[0].namefrst_v[0]", OrderingInfo(1))
        pdfFormFields.SetField("CTR_V41[0].Page2[0].phonenum_v[0]", OrderingInfo(2))
        pdfFormFields.SetField("CTR_V41[0].Page2[0].faclname_v[0]", "MASSACHUSETTS ALLIANCE OF PORTUGUESE SPEAKERS")
        pdfFormFields.SetField("CTR_V41[0].Page2[0].membid_p[0]", Form2.MetroMemberID.Text)
        pdfFormFields.SetField("CTR_V41[0].Page2[0].groupid_p[0]", Form2.MetroGroupID.Text)
        pdfFormFields.SetField("CTR_V41[0].Page2[0].colldate[0]", FilterNumbers(Form2.MetroDOC.Text))
        pdfFormFields.SetField("CTR_V41[0].Page2[0].insconm_p[0]", AuxOption)

        'Page 3
        pdfFormFields.SetField("CTR_V41[0].Page3[0].namelast_p[0]", UCase(Form2.MetroLastName.Text))
        pdfFormFields.SetField("CTR_V41[0].Page3[0].namefrst_p[0]", UCase(Form2.MetroFirstName.Text))
        pdfFormFields.SetField("CTR_V41[0].Page3[0].street_p[0]", UCase(Form2.MetroStAddress.Text))
        pdfFormFields.SetField("CTR_V41[0].Page3[0].city_p[0]", UCase(Form2.MetroCity.Text))
        pdfFormFields.SetField("CTR_V41[0].Page3[0].phonenum_p[0]", FilterNumbers(Form2.MetroPhone.Text))
        pdfFormFields.SetField("CTR_V41[0].Page3[0].specsrce[0]", "4") '4 selects Urine Test
        pdfFormFields.SetField("CTR_V41[0].Page3[0].namelast_v[0]", OrderingInfo(0))
        pdfFormFields.SetField("CTR_V41[0].Page3[0].namefrst_v[0]", OrderingInfo(1))
        pdfFormFields.SetField("CTR_V41[0].Page3[0].phonenum_v[0]", OrderingInfo(2))
        pdfFormFields.SetField("CTR_V41[0].Page3[0].faclname_v[0]", "MASSACHUSETTS ALLIANCE OF PORTUGUESE SPEAKERS")
        pdfFormFields.SetField("CTR_V41[0].Page3[0].membid_p[0]", Form2.MetroMemberID.Text)
        pdfFormFields.SetField("CTR_V41[0].Page3[0].groupid_p[0]", Form2.MetroGroupID.Text)
        pdfFormFields.SetField("CTR_V41[0].Page3[0].colldate[0]", FilterNumbers(Form2.MetroDOC.Text))
        pdfFormFields.SetField("CTR_V41[0].Page3[0].insconm_p[0]", AuxOption)

        'Page 4 
        pdfFormFields.SetField("CTR_V41[0].Page4[0].namelast_p[0]", UCase(Form2.MetroLastName.Text))
        pdfFormFields.SetField("CTR_V41[0].Page4[0].namefrst_p[0]", UCase(Form2.MetroFirstName.Text))
        pdfFormFields.SetField("CTR_V41[0].Page4[0].street_p[0]", UCase(Form2.MetroStAddress.Text))
        pdfFormFields.SetField("CTR_V41[0].Page4[0].city_p[0]", UCase(Form2.MetroCity.Text))
        pdfFormFields.SetField("CTR_V41[0].Page4[0].phonenum_p[0]", FilterNumbers(Form2.MetroPhone.Text))
        pdfFormFields.SetField("CTR_V41[0].Page4[0].namelast_v[0]", OrderingInfo(0))
        pdfFormFields.SetField("CTR_V41[0].Page4[0].namefrst_v[0]", OrderingInfo(1))
        pdfFormFields.SetField("CTR_V41[0].Page4[0].phonenum_v[0]", OrderingInfo(2))
        pdfFormFields.SetField("CTR_V41[0].Page4[0].faclname_v[0]", "MASSACHUSETTS ALLIANCE OF PORTUGUESE SPEAKERS")
        pdfFormFields.SetField("CTR_V41[0].Page4[0].membid_p[0]", Form2.MetroMemberID.Text)
        pdfFormFields.SetField("CTR_V41[0].Page4[0].groupid_p[0]", Form2.MetroGroupID.Text)
        pdfFormFields.SetField("CTR_V41[0].Page4[0].colldate[0]", FilterNumbers(Form2.MetroDOC.Text))
        pdfFormFields.SetField("CTR_V41[0].Page4[0].insconm_p[0]", AuxOption)

        ' report by reading values from completed PDF

        ' flatten the form to remove editting options, set it to false
        ' to leave the form open to subsequent manual edits
        pdfStamper.FormFlattening = False

        ' close the pdf
        pdfStamper.Close()
        pdfReader.Close()
        pdfStamper = Nothing
        pdfReader = Nothing

        Form2.LblStatus.Text = "CTR Forms Sucessfuly Generated."
        Form2.MetroProgressBar.Visible = True
        Form2.MetroProgressBar.Value = Form2.MetroProgressBar.Value + 50
        GenerateForms = True
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Uh OH! Can't Generate Client's Forms!" & vbCrLf & ex.Message) 'vbCrLf = Carriage Return
        GenerateForms = False
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: Provide a minimal example of your problem.

Comment: Using pdfFormFields.SetField to select an answer to Primary Insurance Company name ( on PDF, lab slips pages 2,3 and 4) all options work except for index 15 ("none"). The dropdownlist displays the number 15 instead of the text "none". I think this error has to do with a question on page 1: Insurance Status. All answers work except for "No Insurance". Whenever that's the case, an additional question must be answered. If the client received assistance with enrollment during this visit. I also get the index being displayed instead of the text, as well as an invalid barcode